# How to match strings matching [a-z_]* but with non repetitive symbol "_"

Tags: r, regex

I would like to match strings :

- That are composed by [a-z_] ;
- That doesn't start or end with "_" ;
- That doesn't include repetitive "_" symbol.

So for example the expected matching results would be :

```
"x"; "x_x" > TRUE
"_x"; "x_"; "_x_"; "x__x" > FALSE
```

My problems to achieve this is that I can exclude strings ending or starting with "_" but my regexp also excludes length 1 strings.

```
grepl("^[a-z][a-z_]*[a-z]$", my.string)
```

My second issue is that I don't know how to negate a match for double characters `grepl("(_)\\1", my.string)` and how I can integrate it with the 1st part of my regexp.

If possible I would like to do this with `perl = FALSE`.

Comment: What about `_x_x` or `_x_x_`?

Comment: @akrun suspect they both fail as they start with _. But what about `x_x_x`? Do you want to reject *adjacent* `_` or any string with more than one anywhere?

Comment: They shouldn't be matched because they start or end with "_"

Comment: `x_x_x` should be matched, I would like to reject strings with  leading, trailing or adjacent `_`

Comment: See my answer for the most optimized TRE regex for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following TRE regex:

```
grepl("^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*$", my.string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yj2WyZ/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?:_[a-z]+)*`  - zero or more sequences (`*`) of

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[a-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

See [R demo](http://ideone.com/JDYtAi):

```
my.string <- c("x" ,"x_x", "x_x_x_x_x","_x", "x_", "_x_", "x__x")
grepl("^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*$", my.string)
## => [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect and fully understandable thanks to the detailed explanation

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any questions regarding the current issue do not hesitate to drop a comment. Though I'm on vacation in the mountains, I check SO from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to identify the items correctly:

```
dat <- c("x" ,"x_x","_x", "x_", "_x_", "x__x")
grep("^_|__|_$", dat, invert=TRUE)
[1] 1 2
```

So try:

```
!grepl("^_|__|_$", dat)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Just uses negation and a pattern with three conditions separated by the regex logical OR operator "|".

Comment: If you also want to enforce the usage of only `[a-z_]` use `!grepl("^_|__|_$", dat) & grepl("^[a-z_]+$", dat)`

Comment: This solution will also validate [`"!@!@!@!@!"`](http://ideone.com/nkC2d4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It's the questioner's responsibility to include a range of test cases that span the possibilities in the "real" use case. It's fairly easy to add an or clause that would exclude other [:punct:] items.

Comment: Add "|[^a-zA-Z_]{1,}" as a further condition if you want to exclude non-alpha and non_underscore characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another regex that uses grouping `(` and the `*` for numeration.

```
myString <- c("x_", "x", "_x", "x_x_x", "x_x", "x__x")

grepl("^([a-z]_)*[a-z]$", myString)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So `^([a-z]_)*` matches 0 or more pairs of "[a-z]_" at the beginning of the string and `[a-z]$` assures that the final character is a lower case alphabetical character.

Comment: This matches `"x__"` that should not be matched: `grepl("^([a-z]_)*[a-z_]$", "x__")`: `TRUE`

Comment: Proabably you mean something like `grepl("^([a-z]+_)*[a-z]$", myString)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, [a-z_]$ should be [a-z]$